# What's the best way to use different SQL commands for unit testing only?

Tags: c#

I have a .NET project that uses NHibernate. Due to some project requirements, a very specific section of code uses HQL to select a random record using "order by newid()". However, for unit test purposes, I'm using an in-memory SQLite database, which of course chokes on newid(). I need to have this method use an alternate SQLite compatible query only when run from the unit test. I can't add conditional compilation constants only for unit test purposes, and #define only works at the file level, so I can't simply add a constant there either.

I really don't want to have to muck up my repository class with some junk code just to enable this unit test. What are my options?

Edit:

I already have a global class for other stuff, so I added a static TestMode property to it which will be false any time other than when I explicitly set it in my unit test, so the code now looks like:

```
string random, update;
if (Globals.TestMode)
{
    random = "from Customer order by random()";
}
else
{
    random = "from Customer order by newid()";
}
```

This works, but I'd hoped to avoid exactly such an if statement. Still looking for suggestions.

Comment: Are you unit testing the selection of the random record, or is that simply a dependency of the method you're trying to unit test?

Comment: Kind of both, I guess. The method being tested is supposed to select 1 random record and update a separate table with that record's info. I'm trying to test that (A) the record selected is random and (B) the other table contains the correct info.

Comment: Then you should already have two tests : The first one testing the fact that a random record is returned, and the second one testing the fact that a record is properly inserted into your database.
Otherwise if your test fails, you will have to debug your test to see what exactly failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could abstract out the responsibility of providing the HQL query to a separate class that gets injected into your repository. That way your test code can just inject a different implementation of that class (even a mocked implementation) which provides HQL that you know will work on your SQLite server.

Bear in mind that this isn't really a *unit test* because you're testing a lot more than just your code. In order for your test to pass, you're relying on the database and the NHibernate provider to all be working. Furthermore, it's impossible to deterministically test that a selected record is "random." Unit tests are deterministic. You're describing an *integration test*, as you're trying to test an interaction with the database through an ORM.

The problem is that you're trying to test it using a different database server than you'll actually use in production. This is of questionable value since, as you've noticed, even if the test passes you can't guarantee that the code will actually work in a production environment.